# I have no idea why I am getting "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" ERROR here

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
app = pd.read_excel("/Users/michaelblack/Downloads/Applicants with Interest/Applicants with Interests 2020.xlsx")
app = app.replace(',',' ', regex=True).replace('/','', regex=True).replace('-','',regex=True).replace(';',' ',regex=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
app.fillna(' ', inplace = True)
app.info()
ct = 0
while ct <= 9:
    if ct == 0:
        app['new'+str(ct)] = app['Interest Description'] + ' ' + app['Interest Role']
    else:
        app['new'+str(ct)] = app['Interest Description' + '.' + str(ct)] + ' '+ app['Interest Role' + '.' + str(ct)]
    ct += 1

app.head(5)
```

*My error is on line 12 (right above ct += 1) and it is a "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str".*

For context: every single field in my Excel file is an "object" data type, and I have two other Excel files with the exact same # of columns, column headers, and data types, but just different values, and they both work.

Can anyone please offer some guidance here?  For the life of me, I am lost.  I can't understand why one identical Excel file would work but another wouldn't, when the code is the EXACT same.

Comment: I think you place ] in wrong place try `app['Interest Description'] + '.' + str(ct) + ' '+ app['Interest Role'] + '.' + str(ct)`

Comment: Check the `app['Interest Role' + str(ct)]` column. You may have a number lurking there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding .astype(str) to each column:

```
while ct <= 9:
    if ct == 0:
        app['new'+str(ct)] = app['Interest Description'].astype(str) +' '+ app['Interest Role'].astype(str)
    else:
        app['new'+str(ct)] = app['Interest Description' + '.' + str(ct)].astype(str) + ' '+ app['Interest Role' + '.' + str(ct)].astype(str)
    ct += 1
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't understand why it worked for one Excel sheet but not the other when they're exactly the same.  This seems to work though